# Calculate number of shares needed to buy to reach target price per share

Tags: excel-formula, stock

Let's say you bought 10 shares at $146 a while ago totaling $1460. The price of per share today increased to $300. How many ***new*** shares do I need to buy to get the average price of all shares to, say, $200? Below is my excel. The answer in this scenario is 5.4 shares. How do I put this logic in a formula?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following:

```
=B2*(B7-B3)/(B6-B7)
```

[image]